# Python virtualenv: The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: windows, python-2.7, virtualenv

Following this tutorial [virtualenv](http://timmyreilly.azurewebsites.net/python-pip-virtualenv-installation-on-windows/) I'm getting this message:

```
C:\Users\Dev\Desktop>mkvirtualenv AndroidKivy
C:\Users\Dev\Envs is not a directory, creating
Running virtualenv with interpreter C:/Python27/python.exe
Overwriting C:\Users\Dev\Envs\AndroidKivy\lib\orig-prefix.txt with new content
New python executable in C:\Users\Dev\Envs\AndroidKivy\Scripts\python.exe
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

I read this [mkvirtualenv results in error: The system cannot find the path specified](https://github.com/davidmarble/virtualenvwrapper-win/issues/14) and using the command `where python.exe`. I have just one python.exe runtime in my PATH, so at first my issue does not fit it.

```
C:\Python27\python.exe
```

Again, found this topic [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29567097/error-using-virtualenvwrapper-win-passing-in-different-python-version). Even executing like this `mkvirtualenv -p C:/Python27/python.exe AndroidKivy` I receive the same error.

**PIP List**:

```
pip (9.0.1)
setuptools (28.8.0)
virtualenv (15.2.0)
virtualenvwrapper-win (1.2.5)
```

Using: **Windows 10** and **Python 2.7**

Comment: Python is found, because virtualenv finds it: `Running virtualenv with interpreter C:/Python27/python.exe`. When is the `path not found` error occurring exactly? Can you try running `virtualenv venv`?

Comment: I ran it and none error mentioned above was returned. What I do?

Comment: By the way, none folder was created

Comment: I got the same error with python 3.6

Answer (score 1):

I am using windows
I had old python files (I updated python 3.8 to 3.12) in my `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python`
I was using python 3.12 but venv wrapper tried to use 3.8 ones

I deleted old files and it started to work