# Creating Virtual environment using python 3.8 when python 2.7 is present

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I am trying to create a virtual environment using mkvirtualenv with python 3 in Windows but the environment is created with python 2.7.My pip version is also from python 2.7 which i have avoided using

```
py -m pip install virtualenvwrapper-win
```

When i do

```
mkvirtualenv test
```

environment is created with python 2.7
Please help me with a solution 
Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error using virtualenvwrapper-win passing in different python version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29567097/error-using-virtualenvwrapper-win-passing-in-different-python-version)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvirtualenvwrapper%5D+different+python+versions

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you would like to create a virtualenv with `python 3.X` having the version `2.X`

You just have to pass a parameter argument for your virtual env.

```
$ virtualenv venv -p $(which python3)
```

This command will point to your current python3 install folder, and create a virtualenv copied from your current python3 binaries.

If you would like to see what this command does, just fire the command:

```
$ which python3
#should print your current python3 binary folder.
```

Answer (score 14):

you need install python3.8 to your enviroment, if you are in ubuntu(18.04):

```
sudo apt install python3.8
```

and:

```
mkvirtualenv name_of_the_project -p python3.8
```

Comment: instead of 
`mkvirtualenv name_of_the_project -p python3.8`

this worked for me
`virtualenv name_of_the_project -p python3.8`