# How can I get all the addresses associated with my public key with bitcoinlib?

Tags: python, bitcoinlib

I want to get all the addresses associated with my extended public key. I found how to do this on [bitcoinlib's docs](https://bitcoinlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/bitcoinlib.keys.html):

> Initialize an Address object. Specify a public key, redeemscript or a hash.
>
> ```
> >>> addr = Address('03715219f51a2681b7642d1e0e35f61e5288ff59b87d275be9eaf1a5f481dcdeb6', encoding='bech32', script_type='p2wsh')
> >>> addr.address
> 'bc1qaehsuffn0stxmugx3z69z9hm6gnjd9qzeqlfv92cpf5adw63x4tsfl7vwl'
> ```

However I'm having issues getting `Address()` function to work, since my code:

```
from bitcoin import *  # using import * because not sure what else to import?
master = Address("my extended pub key", encoding='bech32', script_type='p2wpkh')
print(master.address)
```

Produces this error:

```
NameError: name 'Address' is not defined
```

Comment: *What* issues? Give a [mre].

Comment: I put my code at the bottom of the post

Comment: Yes, and you say you're having issues, but what does that actually *mean*? Errors? Unexpected outputs?

Comment: Oh I see, added the error.

Comment: `using import * because not sure what else to import` - presumably you need to import `Address` properly

Comment: That could very well be the issue but I'm not sure what to import, using `bitcoinlib.keys import Address` says `bitcoinlib` isn't a module

Comment: But then, what solved your issue fiji? I added an answer with a generic approach so you can test creating a virtualenv and installing it there.

Comment: I uninstalled python3.9 completely so all my programs were forced to use 3.8 which it worked using 3.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> from bitcoin import *
> ```

Using `import *` is not a good practice. Not only does this import stuff that you don't need and you don't know what exactly it imports, it also does *not* import what you do need in this case.

According to the documentation you have linked, you need to use this import statement:

```
from bitcoinlib.keys import Address
```

Comment: I tried that but that gives `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bitcoinlib'`

Comment: Did you install the same library for which you have linked the documentation?

Comment: Yes, bitcoinlib.

Comment: @fiji `pip install bitcoinlib` and then `from bitcoinlib.keys import Address` worked well to me.

Comment: Seems very odd, my VSC and PyCharm both used Python 3.9 (where bitcoinlib wouldn't install) rather than Python3.8 which I set my project to use. Alas, it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the bitcoinlib library and check the addresses associated with your extended public key, you should do as follows:

```
pip install bitcoinlib
```

After that, using the Python binary where this package was installed, open a Python terminal and say:

```
from bitcoinlib.keys import Address
```

Needless to say it is recommendable to use a virtualenv and also that `import *` is not a very good idea. See the following Q&A to get more details on it:

- [Creating Virtual environment using python 3.8 when python 2.7 is present](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61908834/1983854)
- [Why is "import *" bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2386714/1983854)